# How to Securely Convert Open ID Connect Tokens to Cookies

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, single-page-application, access-token, openid-connect

We have a client application we would like enable SSO via OIDC. The client app is an SPA with a dedicated back-end API. Currently, authentication is implemented via cookies and authorization is enforced at the back-end based on the user of the Auth_Cookie. After the OIDC authentication completes, we would like to continue to leverage these existing local cookie-based code/logic, which also avoids the need to store the tokens with the SPA.

Upon completing the Auth Code PKCE Flow, the front-end SPA would have received the ID_Token and Access_Token directly from the OP's `/token` endpoint. To get from ID/Access_Token to Auth_Cookie, an approach could be:

1. Front-end SPA makes a back-end API call for authentication (e.g. `/authenticate`), passing the Access_Token
2. Back-end validates Access_Token and issues Auth_Cookie

Since, the ID_Token is meant only for the client app (which is the front-end SPA in this context), my assumption is it has no role in this sequence (though logically, you would think a call to the back-end API's `/authenticate` endpoint should supply something resembling credentials, e.g. ID_Token).

Does the above approach make sense and are there any security issues/concerns with it? Are there alternative/better approaches for essentially converting the front-end OIDC authenticated context to cookies?

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to make your backend process the auth redirect - to make it an OAuth2 client instead of your SPA. Your SPA doesn't need the tokens and there will be no need to transfer access token to the backend. The backend handler, which would receive an auth code, would get tokens and create the auth cookie (with all security params).

If you need to keep your SPA as OAuth2 client, then your proposed solution is probably good.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As you suggested, my initial thought was to apply the standard Auth Code Flow, with the back-end handling the auth_code/token exchange - it have would worked quite well. However, my decision swayed after reading that Auth Code + PKCE is now recommended for ALL scenarios (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1.1). Can we use Auth Code + PKCE, with the back-end completing the token exchange? If yes, then the front-end SPA starts the OIDC flow, while the back-end completes it. Would the front- or back-end be considered the client app?

Comment: PKCE is something like "client secret for public clients". Since browser based and native (mobile, desktop) applications cannot keep a secret, they use PKCE. Server applications can use a secret and it serves the same purpose - even if an auth code gets stolen, it cannot be used without a client secret or a code_verifier. If you use your backend as a client, the backend should initiate the authentication redirect, because it knows its redirect URIs and can generate a `state` value (and verify it later).

Comment: I like your very careful approach to thinking about the issues Sherman. I've updated my original answer with a bit more info on token storage. There is not a one size fits all answer, but hopefully my feedback makes you aware of the main factors.

Comment: @JánHalaša My understanding is as well, that the back-channel client_secret should achieve the same result as PKCE, but just not sure why it's recommended now for ALL scenarios. That makes sense that the back-end would be considered the client, as it would be the one initiating the redirect (not actually the SPA, as I had incorrectly thought).

Comment: If all clients must use PKCE, then you should be able to use it even with your backend as a client - along with its client secret. I don't know why its mandatory for all clients, but using both a secret and a PKCE verifier is safer than just PKCE, since PKCE hashing algorithm could theoretically be broken by an attacker.

Comment: @GaryArcher Thanks again for following-up with updates to your answer (and I think blog content too?). As there doesn't seem to be a hardened security mechanism around protecting access_tokens on the browser side (apart from the few different options that still have considerable drawbacks, e.g. store only in memory or html 5 session). For now, I think we will keep the cookie-based approach, and when we expand to clients outside our domain, will then evaluate the different cookie-less options as suggested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interesting discussion Sherman - you made me realise I was not quite doing things right, so I've updated some of my stuff.

**OPTION 1 - COOKIES**

This can make a lot of sense, especially if you don't need cross domain capabilities yet. A full commitment to being cookieless might also be a lot of work.

**OPTION 2 - COOKIELESS WITH TOKENS STORED IN MEMORY**

It is possible to build a totally cookieless SPA and still deal with usability issues such as the user refreshing the page without needing to re-login. It has a prerequisite on an Authorization Server that properly supports the prompt=none parameter though.

- [Code from a working sample that does this](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Write up on In Memory Token Storage](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/08/ui-token-management)
- [Write up on Renewing In Memory Tokens](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/)

**OPTION 3 - COOKIELESS WITH TOKENS STORED IN HTML5 SESSION STORAGE**

As we've discussed, this is not perceived as secure by many, so best avoided if possible. You might consider using it if your Authorization Server does not support prompt=none.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for linking your blog - it was a very useful and informative read, especially the part about the benefits of cookie-less approach. Right now, the client app is actually already part-way into adopting OAuth2/OIDC, where the cookie itself stores an encrypted JWT. Additional security measures around the cookie are already in-place to prevent the usual vulnerabilities, such as XSS or CSRF. The main reason we adopted the cookie approach is because it seems to be the easiest and safest way to securely store the token on the SPA.

Comment: Ok - worth clarifying your exact concerns about using tokens in a browser - interested in your thoughts on this. The [guidance for browser based apps](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04) do not have a problem with tokens, though I realise not everyone is comfortable with this.

Comment: Excerpt from link you reference:
_An additional concern with handling access tokens in a browser is that there is no secure storage mechanism where JavaScript code can keep the access token to be later used in an API request. Using an OAuth flow results in the JavaScript code getting an access token, needing to store it somewhere, and then retrieve it to make an API request. Instead, a more secure design is to use an HTTP-only cookie between the JavaScript application and API so that the JavaScript code can't access the cookie value itself._

Comment: We took the approach suggested there to use an HTTP-only cookie for storing/transporting the token. Granted, we understand there would be some limitations (also noted in your blog), but we wanted to make sure the token could be safely stored/transported from the SPA to the back-end API.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to use cookies for the time being then. One final comment is that you made me realise I could update my samples to be more secure by storing tokens only in SPA memory so I've updated to that model. Note that there is still a way to deal with the user reloading the page. Details above in case useful in future.

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer, Gary. Your feedback and input have been extremely helpful, and would definitely be applied in the next iteration of our migration efforts to OIDC. I'm glad that our discussion also helped you in some ways as well. At the moment, I will be accepting Jan's answer, as it does address my original question, for a cookie-based solution, more directly. Thanks, again, Gary.